# how to get updated values from spring config server if we have many microservices?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I read some articles about spring cloud config server and I understood that we need to add spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency in our application. Also where ever config properties are used we need to add @RefreshScope annotation on beans. And call /refresh endpoint on microservice.

Now what if there many microserivces that uses these properties that uses these properties suppose 30 microservices, do we need to call /refresh endpoint on all these 30 microservice. Also what if a microservice have multiple instances what do we need to do in that case?Is it a good approach to use centralized configuration using spring cloud config server?

Comment: You read wrong (or at least only a part of the solution). You can also use a queue to publish a refresh message that will trigger the refresh for all your microservices. This is also explained in the Spring Cloud Config documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus). Which I suggest to give a read.

Comment: spring cloud bus which you are looking for.